# CodeIgniter - displaying success or unsuccess message

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im wondering if someone could let me know how they handle success / unsuccess messages in CodeIgniter.

For example, what im doing at the moment when a user signs up to my site, this is what happens in the controller

```
if (!is_null($data = $this->auth->create_user( $this->form_validation->set_value('username'), $this->form_validation->set_value('password') ))) {
    // Redirect to the successful controller
    redirect( 'create-profile/successful' );
} else {
    // Redirect to the unsuccessful controller
    redirect( 'create-profile/unsuccessful' );
}
```

Then in the same controller (create-profile), i have 2 methods which are like the following

```
function successful()
{
    $data['h1title'] = 'Successful Registration';
    $data['subtext'] = '<p>Test to go here</p>';

    // Load the message page
    $this->load->view('message',$data);
}
```

The problem with this is that i can simply go to site.com/create-profile/successful and it will show the page.

If someone could possibly show me a better way of handling this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Think about using flash session data. Printing alert or success message whenever it detects the session data will be much more efficient, rather than making separate pages for every success/failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is there a reason you don't use this:

```
if (!is_null($data = $this->auth->create_user( $this->form_validation->set_value('username'), $this->form_validation->set_value('password') ))) {
    $data['h1title'] = 'Successful Registration';
    $data['subtext'] = '<p>Test to go here</p>';

    // Load the message page
    $this->load->view('message',$data);
} else {
    $data['h1title'] = 'Unsuccessful Registration';
    $data['subtext'] = '<p>Test to go here</p>';

    // Load the message page
    $this->load->view('message',$data);
}
```

greets,
stefan

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to make sense ... this would eliminate the extra url segment aswell wouldnt it

Answer (score 6):

You could set a [flashdata](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) before the redirection:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('create_profile_successful', $some_data);
redirect( 'create-profile/successful' );
```

```
function successful(){
    if( FALSE == ($data = $this->session->flashdata('create_profile_successful'))){
        redirect('/');  
    }

    $data['h1title'] = 'Successful Registration';
    $data['subtext'] = '<p>Test to go here</p>';

    // Load the message page
    $this->load->view('message',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redirecting, just show different views.

Here is some sample code:

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
{
    // handle form submission
    if (!is_null($data = $this->auth->create_user( $this->form_validation->set_value('username'), $this->form_validation->set_value('password') )))
    {
        // show success page
        $data['h1title'] = 'Successful Registration';
        $data['subtext'] = '<p>Test to go here</p>';

        // Load the message page
        $this->load->view('message',$data)
    }
    else
    {
        // show unsuccessful page
        $data['h1title'] = 'Unsuccessful Registration';
        $data['subtext'] = '<p>Test to go here</p>';

        // Load the message page
        $this->load->view('message',$data)
    }
}
else
{
    // show login page
    $data['h1title'] = 'Login';
    $data['subtext'] = '<p>Test to go here</p>';

    // Load the message page
    $this->load->view('login',$data)
}
```